# Django "ValueError: embedded null byte"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I just installed Django and changed the DATABASES from sqlite3 to mysql in settings.py, but when I runserver, "ValueError: embedded null byte" occurs occasionally.
What should I do?

- Python 3.6.1
- Django version 2.2.1

```
(myproject) bash-3.2$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 577, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 562, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 280, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 286, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 326, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 342, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 241, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "/Users/mydir/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 132, in iter_modules_and_files
    results.add(path.resolve().absolute())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1122, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 349, in resolve
    return _resolve(base, str(path)) or sep
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 331, in _resolve
    target = accessor.readlink(newpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 443, in readlink
    return os.readlink(path)
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Comment: maybe help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731132/mysterious-embedded-null-byte-error/38731324

Comment: @mehdi Thank you, but this didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, debugging it looks like it is being caused by the introduction of watchman in v2.2.0 as downgrading to v1.9.0 removes it.

What is weird is that sometimes the server will start, the error doesn't seem to occur every time however I am fairly sure it is due to the virtual environment.

**Fixes:**

Disable reload (not ideal)

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Create a watchman config and ignore venv

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#ignore_dirs

However I can't actually get ignore_dirs to work...

**Django ticket**

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30506

Comment: Thanks for comment!
This was the correct answer.
You're completely right, it doesn't happen every time.
` --noreload` works great.

Answer (score 0):

this is my mysql setting.

```
 DATABASES = {
       'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         'NAME': 'novoair',
         'USER': 'root',
         'PASSWORD': 'root@123',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '3306',
     },
 }
```

user name password host port set to your according

Comment: Thank you, I copied and used it, but there was no change.