# PyPDF merge two PDFs

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm working with Python and Django and want to merge several PDF's into a single one.

I've seen several answers to this question, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945454/433737) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41199768/433737), which I've tried to apply but I'm getting errors.

First, this is the PDF data I'm working with:
In my example, I have these two PDFs:

```py
type(pdf1) = <class 'bytes'>
type(pdf2) = <class 'bytes'>
```

And if I `print()` them, they look like this:

```py
b'%PDF-1.5\n%\xb5\xed\xae\xfb\n4 0 obj\n<< /Length 5 0 R\n   /Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx\x9c\x85Vmo\xdb6\x10\xfe\xae_q(VT\x06f\x99\x94\xac7 \x0b\x90\xa6.\x96\x01u\xdbD\xdf\x82\xc1\x90%\xca\xe6&\x93.E95\x86\xfd\xf7\x92\xa2$S\xa9\x87\xc1\xb0$\x92\x0f\x1f\xde=w<\x12\x03R\xbf9V\x8fd\x89\xa188\xdf\x1c\xd4\xf5\x89\x1d,r\x04\xbb\xc6y\x9f9\xd8\xefq>\x84\x91\xe7\x87\x10\xc5^\x90.\xc3\x00Cvp\x16\xd5\x1c\xcd\x11\xa8\xef\xcaq\xffy\x0b\r\x91p\xccwd#\xa9\xac\t\xfc\x06o\xd6\\\xd2\x82\x00\xaf\xe0\x91P\xd6\xc8\\\x92\x03a\xf2\r\xbc\xfd\x17\xcc\x84Y\xf6\x97\xa3\x17\xf0p\x14\xa2 \x85\xact\xdc:o\xe4F\x90\x82\xd0\x13)7\xf9\x81\xb7Lj\xb6_B\xe4!dM\x86R\x11\x8eH\r\xc1x\x8e\xc2\xb9\x8fp\xa2a3\xe7\n{?\xb5\xd9\xf3\x97M^\x14\x9a\\\xbd%=QyV\x14R\xb4\xc4Z\xa1\x835t\xc7r\xd9\n\xb2\xd9\x93\xbc\xecAW\xc9\xcdD\xca\x8a\xba-\t\xbc\xfb@\xaa\xbc\xad%\xfc\xae\xa6\x11\xf1N\xf3j\x87S/L\xd3$\\\x1aq\xc7\x96\x8f#\xc5\xb5D\x91\x0f8\x89\xbd\x08\xc78Iz\xa1\xf1 \xf4\xb3\xbb\xfe\x9c=\xdc\xaf\xe0\xf3Gx\\=\xac\x9f\xb2Y\x18\xbaw\xfa\x91\xad>\xad\xd6\x19\xcc\xfe\xcc\xfe\xf89r>\x8a=\x1d8\xf5\xf9*t\xcf\xee5\x93\xbf\xcc\x96\xd8\xe55-\xce\xf0\xc0*nl\xd7\xcc\xb1\x97 \xe4\xa7\x81\xe1\x1f[\xfd*a\xe8a\x1c\xf8I\x97 \xcfn\xb6\xa7\xcdl\x1e\xc5.t\xcf\x17Z\xd7c3q\x1b"N\xc4\x1a\xcem,\xebrG\x7f:=\\\xeesi\x01\xe4~2w\xcb-\xae\xc4\xadi#Ii\x01\x8e\x9d33\xe7\xd2C\x9b\xa6\xb5 \x89\xbb=[x\xde\n\xabU\xf0\xc31gg\x0b\xbcW\xd6Zd[B\x98\x85\x17C\xbe\x97\xaf\xfdK\x06\xfe\xaa\x1f\xd1\xa2N#\xdc\xa10^\xf8h\xa1Sy@X\x11\xeb\x1d`\xdd\x90I\xc2x\x99\x04\x91N\xc2gW\xa7\xb5(s\xa6\xe5\x0b;\xacR^\xee\xfbFh\x94\xeb\x07$\x11\x87f\x1c\xc9Y9|;\xcagVRI9\xd3f\x9bqm\xb4M\xd2w\xf7\xda\xe2 p\xbd\x919\x1bVq\xd4S\xd8\xfb\x7f\x84\xd0\xcb\xca\xc4x\xf9\xa4T\x86\x9b\x1bX\xdc\x15\xb2\xcd\xeb\x8c|\x97pS\x91\xaaB(\x8a\xf4\xff\x16no\xe1\xfd\x87{#\x086\x82\xdc \x84\xf0\xad\xdaY\xabO\xf7\xaf\x94"zk_\xdc\xe5\xcc|^\x13=\xfc_\xcd\'\x02\xb9/\xf9\xc5|+\xdeWCR\xaa\x821\xc7A\x17|\x1c\xa4\xae\xe4C\xf3\x9a%z\xe4n\xd7)\xa5\xc1`z\x1e\xc9\xb7\x96\x8a~\x85\xa9m\xde\x84\xdc\xec\xba\xb1#\x19\xf7\x92E\xa6#i5\xa7\xf1ql\xb6\xfcx\xac)\x99\x12\x1a\xf3\xc7\xd9].XS\x04\xa9\x88 *\xff\xca)U\x9f\'\x13\xd3\xda\xc3\x96\x88\xa9i\xac>O\xe8:\xd1U\xdb\x19\x10%7\xf6\xa4\x96\x83\x96\xee\xd12\x
```

When I try merging them with like this:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

pdfs = [pdf1, pdf2]

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
   merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

I get this error: `embedded null byte`

And when I try merging them like this:

```py
from functools import partial

with open(fpath, 'rb') as f, open(target_fpath, 'wb') as target_f: 
    for _bytes in iter(partial(f.read, 1024), ''):
        target_f.write(_bytes)
```

I get this other error: `'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`

I think these errors are caused by the format of the data I'm handling. Should I decode the binary data before being able to apply the solutions I linked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysterious "embedded null byte" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731132/mysterious-embedded-null-byte-error)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with how you imported it. The way I did it was

```
pdf1 = PdfFileReader("path\\to\\file.pdf")
type(pdf1)
```

and I got

```
PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader
```

Comment: Due to how the rest of the codebase is working, I only have access to the binary data, not to the path where they are saved. So I would like to merge them, operating with the binary data if possible.

Comment: I see. I found this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019315/how-do-i-create-a-pdf-file-from-a-binary-code-using-python), so maybe you could convert to PDF from binary, then open the file as binary like ```open(file.pdf, "rb")``` then merge?